# Manipulating JSON object: how to reference and update nested values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am just getting started with this so I am confused about how I would work with the following.

```
// so I believe this really isn't an object just a string representation, but for example please excuse the name
var dataObj = "{'id': 1, 
                'data': { 'color': 'red', 
                          'shape' : 'triangle', 
                          'height' : 100, 
                          'width' : 45, 
                           },
                'id': 2, 
                'data': { 'color': 'blue', 
                          'shape' : 'square', 
                          'height' : 75, 
                          'width' : 67, 
                          },
                'id': 3, 
                'data': { 'color': 'orange', 
                          'shape' : 'circle', 
                          'height' : 89, 
                          'width' :24, 
                          }
                }";
```

so what I am having problems with is how would I update specific subset of the data values by the id (like a SQL UPDATE WHERE kind of thing)? javascript or jquery really doesn't matter to me, just don't know an approach for either.

```
dataObjUpdate(2);    
function dataObjUpdate (passedID) {

    //access the data by the passedID match and update the color to black
}
```

appreciate the help guys....

Comment: JSON is a data serialization format (your object in a string in your question is not valid JSON by the way, JSON uses double quotes). You can remove the quotes and you'll get a valid JavaScript object

Comment: The more important problem with your data format is, that the `id` property occurs multiple times in the serialized object. I think you might want to change to an array of objects, instead of this one object.

Comment: yeah that makes sense....bad example fail :). thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we ignore the comment I left and assume you have a JavaScript object. I see the following problems:

- Your ids are outside of your nested object.
- You're using an object but you want a 'list' you can use an array for that.

Here is how I'd structure the object myself:

```
var data = [{ 
        color : 'red', 
        shape : 'triangle', 
        height : 100, 
        width : 45, 
        id:1
    },
    { 
        color: 'blue', 
        shape : 'square', 
        height : 75, 
        width : 67, 
        id: 2
    },
    {
        color: 'orange', 
        shape : 'circle', 
        height : 89, 
        width :24,
        id :3 
    }];
```

Now, I can query it like you'd expect using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var id3 = data.filter(function(elem){
             return elem.id === 3;
          })[0];
   id3;//the third object, with id 3
```

ES6 has a method called `find` which would save the `[0]` at the end (which means the first element)

```
var id3 = data.find(function(elem){
             return elem.id === 3;
          });
   id3;//the third object, with id 3
```

Or, you can use a simple for loop

```
var id3 = (function find(arr){
              for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                  if(arr[i].id === 3){
                      return arr[i];
                  }
              }
          })(data);
id3;
```

Comment: A dictionary keyed by id also makes (and is more performant).  That is if id's are unique

Comment: Yes, that's a valid point, indexing IDs in another object (or map) could be very beneficial. If you're storing a lot of data and only support modern browser, you should also consider IndexedDB. Not to mention that if IDs are sequential you can access elements through the array index.

Comment: thanks Benjamin! i appreciate the help/direction! I don't quite understand the method for indexing, but I suppose that is another question :). appreciated!

Comment: @Justin You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer if it solves your issue. Also, I suggest the JavaScript objects/arrays chapter in eloquent JavaScript or the part on objects in mdn, it explains it nicely. Good luck!

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum one final question, your first example using filter, how would i show the contents of id3 in the console. I have tried simply console.log(id3), console.log(id3.id)etc and everything returns undefined

Comment: yeah...i must be doing something wrong somewhere else. was trying to declare = []; then query and push each {} into the array...guess i am doing that piece wrong. thanks again.

Comment: figured out my mistake btw...examples work great! once again..thanks!